# What is the default software to play single audio files?

Tags: 15.04, music, default-programs

As far as I know, Ubuntu ships Rhythmbox as the default proper music player for a library collection.

What is the default software to play single audio files straight from a folder?

By default, Ubuntu suggests me to open mp3 files with Videos which, to me, does not seem to be the appropriate default application.

[image]

Comment: "What is the default software to play single audio files straight from a folder?" I'm not sure there's a way to set single mp3 files to play with one application and a folder or multiple mp3 files or a playlist of mp3 files to play with another application if that's what you're asking about.

Comment: I was more questioning why Ubuntu doesn't ship a simple audio player and by default plays mp3 files with a Video program.

Answer (score 0):

For me default to play mp3 is Banshee.

To set Banshee as default you can do "Open with" ->  "Open in other program" -> select or write there Banshee and check "use as default"

Comment: Banshee is not installed on my default Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Do exactly same with Rhythmbox